# MPMoviePlayerController .mp4 format not supported in iPhone device

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

hii,
    I am playing a video on iPhone in MPMoviePlayerController but it is not supporting .mp4 format it is showing "This video format is not supported"  while when playing video of format .mov it is playing easily,can u help me out of this.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest answer is that the video needs to be converted to a codec/resolution/bitrate that the iPhone OS supports.  Handbrake, Xilisoft, and others have specific settings for iPhone/iPod.  Use one of those, convert using the specific settings, and try again.